# UCI dataset: How to extract features and change the data into usable format after reading the data on python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing

I am looking to apply some ml algorithms on the data set from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/University.
I noticed that the data is unstructured. Indeed, I want the data to have the features as the columns and have observations as the rows. Therefore, I need help with parsing this dataset.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Below is what I have tried:

```
column_names = ["University-name"
 ,"State"
 ,"location"
 ,"Control"
,"number-of-students"
,"male:female (ratio)"
 ,"student:faculty (ratio)",
 "sat-verbal"
 ,"sat-math"
,"expenses"
,"percent-financial-aid"
,"number-of-applicants"
,"percent-admittance"
,"percent-enrolled"
,"academics" 
,"social"
,"quality-of-life"
,"academic-emphasis"]
data_list =[]
data = ['https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning- 
databases/university/university.data','https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine- 
learning-databases/university/university.data',...]' 


for file in in data:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names = column_names)
    data_list.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not structured in a way you can parse it using pandas. Do something like this:

```
import requests
data = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/university/university.data" 
data = requests.get(data)
temp = data.text
import re
fdic = {'def-instance':[], 'state':[]}
for col in fdic.keys():
    fdic[col].extend(re.findall(f'\({col} ([^\\\n)]*)' , temp))
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(fdic)
```

The output:

[image]